# FASM DLL with C executable error 0xc000007b

Tags: assembly, dll, fasm

I created a dll library in FASM and now i want to use it in my C project but i get error when i want to open the executable file (which generated by C (GCC))

**FASM dll code:**

```
FORMAT  PE64 CONSOLE DLL
ENTRY   _entry

include 'EXPORT.INC'

section '.code' code readable executable

_entry:
        mov     eax, 1
        ret

func:
        mov     eax, 5
        ret

section '.edata' export data readable

        export 'libs.dll', func, 'func'

section '.reloc' fixups data readable discardable
```

**C (CMake):**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(untitled6 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(untitled6 main.c)

target_link_libraries(untitled6 "D:\\untitled6\\libs.dll")
```

**C Code:**

```
int
main() {
    int i;
    asm volatile ("call\tfunc" : "=a"(i));
    return i;
}
```

when i try to open the executable file, i get this error:
**D:\untitled6\libs.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or contains an error .... Error status 0xc000007b**

both executable and DLL are for 64-BIT ... but i really don't know what is the problem !!!

Comment: [This forum thread](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=17916) contains a 64-bit DLL example by the original FASM author which supposedly works.

Comment: Why are you using inline asm to run a `call` instruction in a way that violates the calling conventions, e.g. not reserving shadow space?  If any lazy dynamic linking has to happen, you could have code stepping on main's return address.  (IDK if Windows ever does that; perhaps not).  Just declare a prototype for `func` and do `int i = func();` like a normal person to get the compiler to emit a `call` for you.

Comment: it's not possible since i have my own registers for that function ... that's a simple example to find out the real problem (which was "data fixups \n end data" (i have to add this)) ... but i use my own registers to pass the parameter so i have to use inline asm ... and shadow space is not for here since no Windows function is called in my function (my function is independent to kernel functions)

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem is that the Windows will not load images (.DLL) that do not use any of Window's function. This is because you've got "0xC000007B" - "STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT". This is windows "feature".
2. If you are developing a library for C++, you must use the C++ calling convention (cdecl). In flat assembler (FASM), you can do it like this:

> proc func c

Examples:

library (FASM x64):

```
; libs.asm
format PE64 console DLL
entry DllEntryPoint

include 'win64a.inc'
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.text' code readable executable

proc DllEntryPoint hinstDLL,fdwReason,lpvReserved
  invoke GetModuleHandleA, 0
  mov eax, TRUE
  ret
endp
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
proc func c
    mov rax, 5
    ret
endp
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.edata' export data readable
  export 'libs.dll', func,'func'
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.reloc' fixups data readable discardable
  if $=$$
    dd 0,8              ; if there are no fixups, generate dummy entry
  end if
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.idata' import data readable writeable
  library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL'
  import kernel32,\
    GetModuleHandleA,'GetModuleHandleA'
```

test code (FASM x64):

```
; x64 (ANSI) test
format PE64 GUI 5.0
entry start

include 'win64a.inc'
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.text' code readable executable

  start:
    sub     rsp,8           ; Make stack dqword aligned
    cinvoke  func
    cinvoke  wsprintfA, buffer, _fmt, rax
    invoke  MessageBox, NULL, buffer, _title, MB_ICONINFORMATION+MB_OK
    invoke  ExitProcess,0
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.bss' data readable writeable
  buffer              rb 100h ; 256
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.data' readable
  _title              db 'Title',0
  _fmt                db 'Function result: %d',0
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
section '.idata' import data readable writeable

  library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
          user32,'USER32.DLL',\
          libs,'libs.dll'
          
  import libs, func,'func'

  include 'api\kernel32.inc'
  include 'api\user32.inc'
```